# How to insert comma before last but one and last word in all lines of a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want a batch script to insert comma left to last but one word and between last but one word and last word in all lines of a file. The commas should replace the spaces between the words.

E.g. test file:

```
This is first line
This is the second line
Check Subsystem version 3.1.8-11P
```

I want output look like:

```
This is,first,line
This is the,second,line
Check Subsystem,version,3.1.8-11P
```

This script is inserting comma before the last word, but I have a line in between with & and its deleting that line with & symbol in it.

E.g. *Create & Delete Version  1.1.1*

This line is getting deleted.

```
@echo off
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("Doc.txt") do (
    set "s=%%A"
    set "s1=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!s:@=@a!"
    set "s=!s:\=@b!"
    set "s=!s:/=@f!"
    set "s=!s:.=@d!"
    set "s=!s: =.!"
    for /f "delims=" %%A in (".!s!") do (
        endlocal
        set "s=%%~xA"
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        if defined s (
            set "s=!s:.= !"
            set "s=!s:@d=.!"
            set "s=!s:@f=/!"
            set "s=!s:@b=\!"
            set "s=!s:@a=@!"
            set "s=!s:~1!"
            call set s2=%%s1:!s!=%%
            echo !s2!,!s! >> output.txt
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
pause
```

And also I'm not sure how to insert comma left to last but one word.

Comment: Where is the Windows batch file you require us to help you with? There's a difference between helping somebody you and doing it for them, as it currently stands your request is the latter and is therefore off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with any text editor supporting regular expressions by searching for
`\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)$` and using as replace string `,$1,$2`.

[How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/) contains in one answer the link to latest version of [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by by *Dave Benham* which makes it possible to make this modification on the file using the regular expression search and replace strings.

For usage of **JREPL.BAT** from within a batch file with this additional batch file in same directory as the executed batch file:

```
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)$" ",$1,$2" /F "%~1" /O -
```

`"%~1"` references here in this generic command line the name of the file to modify.

Run `jrepl.bat /?` for help on the other options used here.

Run `call /?` for help on this command and explanation of `%~dp0` (drive and path of current batch file ending with a backslash).

Explanation of the regular expression replace:

- `\W+` ... find 1 or more **non word** character according to Unicode standard.
- `(\w+)` ... find 1 or more **word** character according to Unicode standard and mark the found string for back-referencing in replace string with `$1`.
- `\W+` ... find again 1 or more **non word** character according to Unicode standard.
- `(\w+)` ... find again 1 or more **word** character according to Unicode standard and mark the found string for back-referencing in replace string with `$2`.
- `$` ... search expression results in a positive match only if the two words could be found at end of a line whereby the newline characters are not matched.

---

For a line like

```
Check Subsystem version 3.1.8-11P
```

which should be modified to

```
Check Subsystem,version,3.1.8-11P
```

in the file a different regular expression search string is necessary because of `.` and `-` are **non word** characters according to Unicode standard.

The search string must be modified to: `[^\w.\-]+([\w.\-]+)[^\w.\-]+([\w.\-]+)$`

`[`...`]` is positive character class definition matching any character specified within the square brackets.

`[^`...`]` is a negative character class definition matching any character **not** specified within the square brackets.

`\w` is a special character class definition for all **word** characters according to Unicode standard.

`.` inside square brackets of a positive or negative character class definition is interpreted as literal character. The [dot](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e/index.htm) character would have a special meaning in regular expression search strings outside a character class definition.

`-` inside square brackets of a positive or negative character class definition means all characters **from** character X specified left to `-` **to** character Y specified right to `-` according to code values of the characters X and Y. The [hyphen](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) is interpreted also as literal character if there is no character either left or right to `-` inside the character class definition. However, it is advisable to escape `-` with a backslash inside a character class definition independent on its position within the brackets when the hyphen character should be interpreted as literal character. Outside a character class definition the hyphen character has no special meaning.

So the entire command line to use for a file containing strings with dot and hyphen which should be interpreted as "words" is:

```
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "[^\w.\-]+([\w.\-]+)[^\w.\-]+([\w.\-]+)$" ",$1,$2" /F "%~1" /O -
```